# Google Earth X ArcMap Plugin

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, google-earth, dynamic

I don't think this exists but just wanted to double check with the GIS community. Is there a tool or plugin that connects Google Earth and ArcMap such that when you are in Street View in Google Earth there is dynamic point in ArcMap that moves around relative to your position in Google Earth?

Comment: I would suggest you make a suggestion for this feature to [Esri](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question asked on the [Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/qjLauBb0vjg) three years ago:

> I am trying to link Google Earth to the new version of ArcMap 10.2 and
>   need instructions on how to do so. I want the image that I pull up in
>   ArcMap to link with the location of the image in Google Earth.

It went unanswered and I think that is because the tool or plugin you seek does not exist.